# How does MethodInvoker gets access to members outside its scope?

Tags: c#, .net

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
   List<string> someList = LoadList();
   if(condition)
   {
        MethodInvoker invokeThis = delegate {             
           someList.Remove(0);
        };
        if(this.InvokeRequired)
        { 
           this.invoke(invokeThis);
        }
        else
        {
           invokeThis();
        } 
   }
}
```

What I dont understand is how does invokeThis gets access to `someList`. Shouldnt the scope be limited to delegate { .. };.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the access shouldn't be limited to the `delegate { ... }` block. This is a large part of the benefit of anonymous functions (anonymous methods and lambda expressions) - they're able to *capture* local variables as part of their environment. In this way they implement [*closures*](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx) for C#. Note that these really are variables - if you change the value within the delegate, and then access it within the rest of the method again, you'll see the new value. The variable can live on even after the method has returned, and you can even have multiple "instances" of a local variable - one each time the declaration is logically executed.

See section 7.15.5.1 of the [C# 4 spec](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/D/0BDA894F-2CCD-4C2C-B5A7-4EB1171962E5/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.doc) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

When you have an anonymous delegate or lambda that accesses variables from the function that defines it, the C# compiler automatically restructures your code.

Specifically, it generates a class to hold the locals of that method that is passed to the lambda. You can see this if you inspect the generated code using something like ildasm, Reflector or ILSpy.